# Google Document Feed Ids / Resource Ids Different in Change feed

Tags: google-docs-api, google-drive-api

When using the Google Drive / docs feed to get items, entry comes back with an id and resource id in the following structure:

```
<id>https://docs.google.com/feeds/id/document%3A12345</id>
<gd:resourceId>document:12345</gd:resourceId>
```

We have been using the Google feeds for a while and we use the resource ID as our unique key to a document for getting back to it in the system.  Yet, with the new change feed to get back deleted items, google always seems to give back a resource id of:

```
<id>https://docs.google.com/feeds/id/unknown%312345</id>
<gd:resourceId>unknown:12345</gd:resourceId>
```

Obviously, this causes a failed match by ID.  Is google recommending that we ignore their resource Id and do our own parsing of it to the REAL ID?

It seems pretty silly that you would feed developers one ID in the change feed to reference an item, but they after that item is deleted feed us a totally different ID.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, we have always returned `unknown:[resource_id]` in the changes feed to represent deleted resources, as documented [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#changes_representing_a_deletion).

My recommendation here is that you split on the `:` character, and compare the [untyped resource IDs](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#terminology_used_in_this_guide).

Comment: Hi Vic,  Isn't the change feed relatively new as of Drive?  Yeah, the answer is for me to store both the full id and the partial and then compare by partial.  But this fix adds baggage and overhead to my side that would be great to avoid.

Comment: The change feed is not new as of Drive.  It's been around for 1+ years.  The baggage is required at the moment, but we'll fix it in a future version of the API.